# Modifying the URL with GTM messes up GA's ecommerce metrics

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager

In this e-commerce product variants and site searches are part of the URL, instead of URL parameters, hence interfering with reporting. Since I cannot use a GA's Search&Replace filter because parameters are processed before, I am trying to do it using GTM.

I directly modified the GA Settings variable instead of the tag:
[GA SETTINGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlPMN.png)

Here's the script:

```
function(){
var pattern = /\/p\/.*?(?=(\/|$))/g;
var _url = {{Page URL}};
var url = new URL(_url.replace('/search/', '/?s='));
var new_url = url.pathname.replace(pattern, '') + url.search;
return new_url;}
```

So '/shoes/chucks/p/blue' turns to '/shoes/chucks/'
And '/search/chucks' turns into '/?s=chucks'

All Pages report looks fine. Also Product Detail Views, Add to Cart and (apparently) Checkout. But it stops measuring Purchases.
I'm out of ideas, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: this depends on what ecommerce platform you are using. Are you sending ecommerce tracking directly through your platform using an integration or are you doing it manually through GTM by pushing products and purchases to the datalayer. If the former, then the platform is probably pushing everything on the server side and not client side and something could be broken, it depends on the code. If the latter, make a fake purchase and see if the datalayer for purchase still comes up. If you are using the latter, you may have to reconfigure the datalayer.

Comment: check to see if you can change this in your platform. Using GTM this way, might cause double tracking (make sure that Google Analytics is firing only after the URLs are changed) but it will slow down the site and look strange to users.

Comment: @Jknight thanks for your feedback. E-commerce platform is SAPCommerce, but everything is reconfigured through GTM, while I work IT to bring this to the standard.
I think I have found the problem, or part of it. According to GA's documentation the values have to use "..either &dl or both &dh and &dp have to be specified for the hit to be valid..". Now I have to figure out how to adapt my script to replace those characters, I'm no good at regular expressions, but I'll get around it eventually. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#page